# Create multiple arrays of objects based on property value then iterate through each array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, iterator

Say I have the following objects in an array:

```
var entities = [
    server1: { type: server },
    server2: { type: server },
    server3: { type: server },
    printer1: { type: printer },
    printer2: { type: printer },
    printer3: { type: printer },
    switch1: { type: switch },
    switch2: { type: switch },
    switch3: { type: switch }
]
```

How could I do something like this:

```
typeArray(type) = []
for each type in entities {
    for each entity in entities of type {
        typeArray(type).push(entity)
    }
}
```

This should result in something like...

```
typeArray("switch")(0) = switch1
typeArray("server")(2) = server3
typeArray("printer")(1) = printer2
```

On top of this, then, I would like to be able to programmatically access all arrays

```
for each typeArray() {
    var type = ???
    myArrayFunction(typeArray, type);
}
```

Hopefully my pseudo code makes sense...

Comment: It's really hard to debug pseudocode. Try turning it into JavaScript and let us know if anything goes wrong.

Comment: `var entities = [server1:` is invalid, `[` should be `{` (don't forget to fix closing too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple map() will handle the re-shuffling for you:

```
var entities = {
    server1: { type: 'server' },
    server2: { type: 'server' },
    server3: { type: 'server' },
    printer1: { type: 'printer' },
    printer2: { type: 'printer' },
    printer3: { type: 'printer' },
    switch1: { type: 'switch' },
    switch2: { type: 'switch' },
    switch3: { type: 'switch' }
}

var typeArray={};
Object.keys(entities).map(function(a){
  var v=this[a];
 typeArray[v.type]=typeArray[v.type]||[];
 typeArray[v.type].push(a);
},entities);

typeArray /* ==

{
    "server": [
        "server1",
        "server2",
        "server3"
    ],
    "printer": [
        "printer1",
        "printer2",
        "printer3"
    ],
    "switch": [
        "switch1",
        "switch2",
        "switch3"
    ]
}

*/
 // a sanity check for your suggested code seems to work using js syntax:
 typeArray["server"][2] // == "server3"
```

Comment: This looks nice, so how can I solve the question on line 28 here: http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/D5E77/4/

Comment: @ScottBeeson: Object.keys(typeArray) will return a string array of unique names of any types originally contained in the entities variable.